# How to install packages in debian whitout sudo permission?

Tags: python, django, sudo, shared-hosting, apt-get

I want to up a django server on a shared-hosting domain (debian/jessie). I don't have root permission, so i can-t execute "apt-get install package". I success to run a virtualenv but i need to install some common package to run django successfully.

-libssl-dev
-openssl
-build-essential
-python-dev
-libmysqlclient-dev

I hope someone can help me

Comment: I don't think you can install packages without sudo...

Comment: Doesn't `fakeroot` work? EDIT: no.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a virtualenv, you can install Django 'inside' the virutalenv using the pip tool, and it will become available when you are running the virtual environment.

You have 2 choices, which you can do **while running the virutalenv**:

Either install packages one by one, with `pip install *package name*`

Or create a .txt file named for example requirements.txt, fill up that file with your requirements, for example (the numbers are the version you want):

```
Django==1.9.10
MySQL-python==1.2.5
Pillow==2.3.2
six==1.10.0
```

and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` so that pip installs all those packages at once, also making it very easy to replicate on another machine.

Hope this helps